# Premature end of loop

Tags: python, sqlite, parsing, lxml

The following is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sqlite3
import lxml.cssselect
import lxml.html
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
import urllib

db = sqlite3.connect('abiturient.sqlite')
sql = db.cursor()

query = "DELETE FROM universities"
sql.execute(query)

regions = sql.execute('SELECT * FROM regions')
for region in regions:
    doc = lxml.html.document_fromstring(urllib.urlopen(region[2]).read())

    for topic in doc.xpath('//span[@id="branch2"]/a'):
        name = topic.text_content().replace("'", "''")
        link = 'http://vstup.info/2013' + topic.attrib['href'][1:-5] + 'b.html'
        region_id = str(region[0])

        sql.execute("INSERT INTO universities (id, name, link, region_id) VALUES (NULL, '" + name + "', '" + link + "', '" + region_id + "')")

    print region[1] + ': added.'

db.commit()
db.close()
```

My table `regions` consists of three entries (three links for parsing). I'm selecting them from SQLite and parsing them using `lxml`. But there is one problem: the loop `for region in regions:` performs just one pass (parsing just the first link and stopping without errors). I don't know the reason this happens. Maybe it happens due to having a loop inside a loop?

Comment: Are you sure there are three entries in regions? what if you try to fetchall after execution: `regions = sql.execute('Select...').fetchall()`?

Comment: Not exactly related, but: `TRUNCATE universities` is often better than `DELETE FROM universities`. Also, you `INSERT` by creating one long SQL string, and are very susceptible to injection attacks. Use `?` or conn.escape(x) when building the string.

Comment: Thanks! `fetchall()` helped me! :)

Comment: No, this is unrelated. Just best practices.

Comment: `TRUNCATE universities` makes syntax error. Maybe `TRUNCATE` does not exist in SQLite?

Answer (score 0):

For those of you - like me - coming late to the party, the problem is in the statement:

```
regions = sql.execute('SELECT * FROM regions')
```

What you get back from the execute call *is the cursor you used to make the call.*  The answer, as Rapolas K suggested, is to actually fetch the records using that cursor - like either:

```
regions = sql.execute('SELECT * FROM regions').fetchall()
```

or:

```
sql.execute('SELECT * FROM regions')
regions = sql.fetchall()
```

Comment: `.fetchall()` is over kill - sqlite3 supports using `for row in db.execute('some query')` where the `execute` of the database connection object produces an iterable...

Comment: A very good point, and much cleaner.  You can tell how much I've used sqlite3.  :-)